# After creating a node in activity module I am getting an error "undefined index"

Tags: views

After installing the [Activity](https://www.drupal.org/project/activity) module, there is a default view activity/all.

After creating an activity template I am able to see the view result as I required.
But why am I getting this error?

```
Notice: Undefined index: table in _node_query_node_access_alter() (line 3364 of C:\modules\node\node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: table in _node_query_node_access_alter() (line 3364 of C:\modules\node\node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: table in _node_query_node_access_alter() (line 3364 of C:\modules\node\node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: table in _node_query_node_access_alter() (line 3364 of C:\modules\node\node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: table in _node_query_node_access_alter() (line 3364 of C:\modules\node\node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: table in _node_query_node_access_alter() (line 3364 of C:\modules\node\node.module).
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the issue queue for Activity.

In particular: [Causes undefined index _node_query_node_access_alter](https://www.drupal.org/node/1292760#comment-6985630)

> Not sure why activity would be a culprit of this, but non admin users
>   see this error when viewing default activity view or any other
>   acitivity views created. This error will also occur on a page when the
>   view is a block.
>
> Notice: Undefined index: table in _node_query_node_access_alter()
>   (line 3197 of /var/sites/my/modules/node/node.module).

Comment: thanks for ur reply Reynolds.i opted for heartbeat module where i can customize using rules..